# Connection was refused to port 8100, Got response with unknown status: {"code":"ECONNRESET"} Proxying [GET /status] to

Tags: java, android, ios, selenium, appium

```
public class TestIOSSafariBrowser
{

    @Test
    public void startBrowser() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();


        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"XCUITest");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"iPad_Mini");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"13.3");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
//      cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID,"00008020-000C30860291002E");
                                                        
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID,"00008020-000C30860291002E");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"safari");
        AppiumDriver<MobileElement> appium = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        appium.get("http://www.google.com");
        appium.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
//      System.out.println("Page tile is " + driver.getTitle());
        }
    
}
```

Comment: And my error was

Comment: Hi Anupam, please try to format your code cleanly. What is your question? It helps if you clarify what you expect to happen versus what actually happens. (Also, I don't understand your comment.)

Comment: Hi Thank you for comment, 
My Problem is  while running above code that is for launching google.com in IOS device is not working.

Getting error like 
got response with unknown status: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}
Waiting up to 60000ms for WebDriverAgent to start
Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/status] with no body
Connection was refused to port 8100

For detail of error please see my appium log in comment section

Comment: A quick Google shows other people with this problem didn't set things up correctly. See [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/11293) and [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13320). Did you setup your provisioning profile correctly? Maybe provide more logs. It helps if you provide the versions of things you are working with. What version of iOS? What version of Appium?

Comment: Appium version is - 1.18.0-beta.0
OS version is - MacBook Pro(Mac OS Catalina, 10.15.5 (19F101))
Device OS version on which i'm running my code is - 13.3.1(Ipad_mini)
Xcode version is - 11.4,

ALL logs are already i have pasted in comments section

Comment: You should update your original question with this info rather than leave in the comments. I don't see your full logs in the comments, so please add to the question. It looks like you are running this on iOS, so where are the rest of the iOS logs (like as shown in the links that I provided)?